Как запустить исходный код node js в electron
Имеется задача, необходимо сделать приложение, для загрузки и выгрузки файлов на google drive.
Код взял из оф.документации гугла, создал приложение, сделал кнопку "загрузить файл".
Хотелось бы чтобы при нажатии кнопки, запускался как раз таки код из index.js.
Курил документацию, что мол можно через архив asar запустить код, но что-то у меня не получилось.
Много где смотрел информацию, но так и не допёр как это воссоединить.
Познакомился с React не так давно, поэтому должных знаний пока нет.
Пример кода из Button.tsx:
import './App.scss';

document.querySelector('#download')?.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const cp = require('child_process')
    cp.fork(require.resolve('./resources/index.js'))
})


const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="container">
                <button id='download'>Загрузить файл</button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;

По факту получается что не работает. Уже ума не приложу как их соединить.
Возможно плохо искал. Каким образом можно соединить их?
